# What is the sin incurred of a wife having lllicit sex?

Tags: sin

What is the sin incurred of one's wife having illicit sex?

Answer (score 3):

As per laws of Manu, [V, l66. WOMEN. 197](https://archive.org/stream/lawsofmanu00bh/lawsofmanu00bh_djvu.txt):

> 161. But a woman who from a desire to have 
>        offspring violates her duty towards her (deceased) 
>        husband, **brings on herself disgrace in this world, and 
>        loses her place with her husband (in heaven).**
> 162. **Offspring begotten by another man is here 
>        not (considered lawful), nor (does offspring begotten) 
>        on another man's wife (belong to the begetter), nor 
>        is a second husband anywhere prescribed for virtuous women.**
> 163. She who cohabits with a man of higher 
>        caste, **forsaking her own husband who belongs to 
>        a lower one, will become contemptible in this world, 
>        and is called a remarried woman (paraptarva).**
> 164. By violating her duty towards her husband, 
>        **a wife is disgraced in this world, (after death) she 
>        enters the womb of a jackal, and is tormented by 
>        diseases (the punishment of) her sin.**

In above verses bold part is highlighting the consequences of conducting such sins.